# index.html button navigation to razor page

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I have an application where we have a button in index.html.
So just wanted to navigate from index.html to another razor page
which is in PAGES folder called

```
dashboard.razor
```

I am newbie to blazor applications,please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NavigationManager`.

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager;
@code {
    private void MyButtonClick()
    {
        this.NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/dashboard");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to assign a path for the `dashboard.razor` by the `@page` directive on the above of the component. For example:

```
@page "/dashboard"
```

Now you can access to `dashboard.razor` from everywhere by `/dashboard`. For example, for the `Index.html` button, you can do it such as below:

```
<button onclick="location.href = 'www.yoursite.com/dashboard';" id="myButton" class="float-left submit-button" >Dashboard</button>
```